# how to post data into iframe using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, post, iframe, bootstrap-modal

So i've never use a POST method to get an image preview into iframe. The problem that i am running into is that when i check the network tab, i get the correct responses however i dont get the actual image that i requested.

my controller:

```
$scope.Url = $http.post("/services/v3/documents",                    // 1. url
          {
                "fileTitleText" : "will be the title text of the PDF",
                "widthMeasure" : 612,
                "heightMeasure" : 792,
                "docBag" :
                    [
                        {
                            "bookmarkTitleText" : "doc 1",
                            "applicationNumberText" : "14352947",
                      "previewFile" : "true"
                        }
                    ]
            }                                             // 2. request body
                                                         // 3. config object
      );
```

html:

```
<iframe frameBorder="0" class="modal-iframe" src="{{Url}}" ></iframe>
```

When the browser renders the page...it just loads the base url. If anyone can help me get the post call working that would be great!

Thanks

EDIT:

got some advice i got below to put $scope.url inside a then...here is what i got which did not solve my problem...maybe its the way i wrote it

```
$http.post('/services/v3/documents', 
          {
                    "fileTitleText" : "will be the title text of the PDF",
                    "widthMeasure" : 612,
                    "heightMeasure" : 792,
                    "docBag" :
                        [
                            {
                                "bookmarkTitleText" : "doc 1",
                                "applicationNumberText" : "14352947",
                          "previewFile" : "true"
                            }
                        ]
                }           
        )
        .then($scope.Url);
```

Comment: You appear to be wanting to collect the result of the `$http.post` call, which I think is a promise object. You have to set `$scope.Url` inside a `then` block. Look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Comment: hmm interesting...ill try this out and update!

Comment: You are setting the `src` attribute of iframe, which should be a URL, I see that in your update to your question, you have `then($scope.Url)` This is not going to do anything. The `then` block accepts a callback function. The answer shows its correct use, but what is `response`? Is it a URL? Is it JSON response? . For the iframe to display the correct image, the `src` attribute, _has_ to be a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$http.post('/services/v3/documents', 
      {
                "fileTitleText" : "will be the title text of the PDF",
                "widthMeasure" : 612,
                "heightMeasure" : 792,
                "docBag" :
                    [
                        {
                            "bookmarkTitleText" : "doc 1",
                            "applicationNumberText" : "14352947",
                      "previewFile" : "true"
                        }
                    ]
            }           
    )
    .then(function(reponse){
        $scope.Url = response;
    });
```

Comment: getting a response not defined error code in the console

Comment: hmm now it spits out a 404 (not found error) on GET "GET http://localhost:3000/%7B%22data%22:%22%PDF-.... 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: "response" will be either object or result you are returning on your backend, which one is it?